# Multiple annotations on mkmapview

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview

I have many annotations on mkmapview.To show multiple annotations on mkmapview I am using the code

```
 MKMapRect zoomRect = MKMapRectNull;
 for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in self.mapView.annotations)
 {
       if([[annotation description]isEqualToString:@"Location"])
      {
            MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
            MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0, 0);
            if (MKMapRectIsNull(zoomRect)) 
            {
                        zoomRect = pointRect;
            } 
            else 
            {
                        zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect);
             }
         }
   }

 MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(zoomRect);

[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

Even though the annotations are plotted on the Map, certain annotations are  getting cut off.

[image]

Comment: how many annotations do you want to load?

Comment: @kishore: According to the API response,I need to plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I many, if not most, cases you'll have a pin at the top like that because the rectangle you are calculating is only for the co-ordinates the annotation is pointing at, not for the image shown at that location.

You might be able to find out how far off the screen the annotation view goes using [MKMapView Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/convertPoint%3atoCoordinateFromView%3a) but you'll need to zoom to the incorrect rect first to be able to know the map distance that is covered by a screen measurement.

Another way to do it is to slightly expand your zoomRect northward by a fraction based on the size of the pin compared to the map view size. For example (using made up numbers) if the map view was 100pt high and the pin was 10, you'd need to make your zoomRect 10% taller (assuming there is a pin at the top - you can verify with by checking if the zoomRect is wider than the mapview, or just add 10% on anyway because no-one will care if there is a bit of unused map at the top).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this it may help you

```
- (void)zoomToFitMapAnnotations { 

    if ([mapView.annotations count] == 0) return; 

        int i = 0;
        MKMapPoint points[[mapView.annotations count]];

        //build array of annotation points
        for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in [mapView annotations])
            points[i++] = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);

        MKPolygon *poly = [MKPolygon polygonWithPoints:points count:i];

        [mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect([poly boundingMapRect]) animated:YES]; 


}
```